# Why does using ImageCapture in typescript give an error ？

Tags: javascript, typescript, webapi

I want to use camera to take pictures through typescript. I know that in javascript, `ImageCapture` can be used like this:

```js
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
  .then(mediaStream => {
    document.querySelector('video').srcObject = mediaStream
    const track = mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0];
    imageCapture = new ImageCapture(track);
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

However, when I use this code in typescript, I get an error: `Cannot find name 'ImageCapture'`.

Why is this happening, is there a replacement for ImageCapture in typescript.

I want to know how to take a photo when using typescript.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use properties from web API, you need to call them like this window.property. As typescript will throw an error on calling window.ImageCapture as a quick solution you can do this

```
new (window as any).ImageCapture(track);
```